# Can we add mail tag as a synonym to email tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We currently have a [email](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) tag and an [mail](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) tag. I think we should add mail tag as a synonym to the email tag. I have proposed this synonym which you can see [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms/).

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have set up synonym and merged appropriately.